# Anchor link not scrolling to id tag from another page

Tags: reactjs, safari, next.js

Before posting this I passed one full day to understand this bug but without any result.
Here is the link to web application that Im developing : https://yd-chauffeurs.vercel.app/

This BUG is happening ONLY in SAFARI. Please use SAFARI to reproduce. In other browser it works perfectly.

Open Home page and click on CONTACT after the contact page is opened click on ABOUT (A PROPOS in french) or GALLERY. You will see that SAFARI doesn't scroll to that section which is marked with id.
When you are on Home page and you click , all Links work perfectly and they scroll to necessary id.
But when you are on another page like Contact or FAQ, Safari doesn't scroll to About or Gallery.

I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your answer.
Today I finally managed to resolve the issue. I resolved this problem by giving min-height to service section.
The problem was that Safari was not charging all DOM elements so it was starting to scroll to the section but when DOM was fully loaded the scroll was pushed upper. So I gave min height to service section and now it works perfectly.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I checked in Safari Version 14.1 (Desktop) but cannot reproduce the problem.